# How to handle daylight saving time properly in Java 7 without Joda Time?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone, dst

**Before marking it duplicate read it thoroughly Plus Can't use Joda Time and Java 8 time.util***.

I'm Trying to get the current date of Country with DST Enabled. Since with time zone it get `[local-millis] = [UTC-millis] + [offset-millis]` so i added the `DST_OFFSET` to it to get the time in the DST enabled country, as done on the Linux machine `GMT_TIME + LOCAL_TIME_ZONE_OFFSET + DST_OFFSET` to get the current local time.

The code to print the current Time of [Istanbul](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/turkey/istanbul) Which has currently DST Enabled by 1 hour.

```
public class DstInstanbul {

    public static void main(String...args){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul");

        calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings());


        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        simpleDateFormatLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Istanbul"));

        System.out.println("Current date and time : " + simpleDateFormatLocal.format(calendar.getTime()));


       System.out.println("Current date and time : " + simpleDateFormatLocal.format(calendar.getTime()));
       System.out.println("The TimeZone is : " + calendar.getTimeZone().getID());

    }
}
```

Which Gave me the Correct output

```
Current date and time : 2015-11-01 20:49:54
The Hour of the Day is : 20
The TimeZone is : Europe/Istanbul
```

But since the above code is not so much of generic so i tried to add following line, so that if only the daylight is enabled then only add
the dstSaving So i changed the following `calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings());` with

```
if (timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
            calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings());
       }
```

But the Problem is if i do so i get the output without any DST. and printing `System.out.println(timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date()));` gives me false and hence the result but the daylight saving is there as you can see in this link [Istanbul clock](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/turkey/istanbul)

```
Current date and time : 2015-11-01 19:54:49
The TimeZone is : Europe/Istanbul.
```

The same logic for the time zone [Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/brazil/rio-de-janeiro) gives me true for inDaylightTime but displays a result one hour ahead now

Ideone link for all the code ordered in a way discussed 1. https://ideone.com/4NR5Ym 2.https://ideone.com/xH7vhp 3.https://ideone.com/tQenb5

My question is what is the problem with `timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date())` with Istanbul Time Zone. Why it's showing false. Why for Brazil i'm not getting current DST time even when the `inDaylightTime` is true.
What is the proper way to handle such situation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a few questions about time zones and daylight savings in Turkey today.

This is likely because [Turkey has changed the date for the daylight savings switch from November 1 to November 8.](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-34631326)

The timezone data in your JVM may not be current with the change.  [Oracle has an update for their JVM.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html)

The timezone data updater that you download from the link above is an executable jar file.  To update your JVM on a unix host:

```
sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar --update --location http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

The tool doesn't seem to output anything on updates, so to verify run:

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar --version
```

The version of the timezone data with the Turkey update is `tzdata2015g`

Comment: Ok got it .. but for brazil without that calendar.add i'm getting correct output means no addition of dst is required can you suggest why ?

Comment: Cannot do it in Windows! I have exception even with `GitBash`: `Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:268)
`

Answer (score 4):

You should not do this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings());
```

Nor should you do this:

```
if (timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings());
}
```

You do not need to adjust the time manually.  It is done for you automatically based on the date you are formatting.   Calling `add` just moves the instantaneous point in time you are working with.

Remove those lines, and update your JVM to take in the latest Turkish DST change (as Monz described in his answer), and you should be good to go.

Comment: Right, manipulating the Calendar value directly to adjust for daylight savings is not correct.  Changing a Calendar object's time value is actually changing the time an event occurred (or whatever that Calendar value is meant to represent.)  Time *zone* changes adjust the time's *displayed* value (that's why a fully formatted time string always includes a time offset.)  Here's a post I wrote about this just today:  http://monztech.com/index.php/2015/11/01/daylight-savings-for-developers/